# Диаграммы классов на основе dll

Tags: uml, классы, dll

Здравствуйте!

Возникла необходимость построить диаграмму классов на основе **dll**. Наподобие диаграммы классов,которую делает нам **Visual Studio** (кнопочка **View Class Diagram** в окне **Solution Explorer**).

Есть конечно такой замечательный продукт как **ILSpy** - через него код выдирать из dll, а потом вручную что-то стряпать (на крайний случай **Object Browser** в том же Visual Studio, но там только классы с методами и полями можно просмотреть).

Где-то видел, что есть такая программа - **QuickAssemblyGrapher** (позволяет строить диаграммки по классам с зависимостями) на codeproject, к сожалению не нашел. Также **MS Visio**, но это не то.
В принципе есть идейка сделать такую диаграмму средствами **VS + ILSpy**, но она слишком трудозатратная (по времени).
Может кто-то знает или встречался с такими программами, которые могут генерировать диаграммы классов с зависимостями на основе "скормленной" им dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Программку так и не нашел, но нашел отличный способ как решить эту проблему ))
Использовал для этого **.Net Reflector** - в нем открыл требуемую dll'ку сохранил со всеми ее потрохами (включая ресурсы и тд.). 
Открываю сохранившийся проект в **VS** и делаю диаграмму там (кнопочка **View Diagram Class** в окошке **Solution Explorer**), довожу до приемлемого вида и сохраняю в .png (контекстное меню **Export Diagram as image**). Буквально пара минут и готово.
Жаль .Net Reflector платный, а вот в **ILSpy'е** одним кликом сохранить не получится, только по отдельности, а если классов 100'ня и более вообще пипец ((.